# Describing the equivalence classes (x, y)R geometrically.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let say (x, y) R (s, t) if  x + t = y + s and I have already proven that R is an equivalence relation, however, I need to show the equivalence classes (x, y)R geometrically. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Use latex and tell us which space we are dealing with

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $a$ be any real number. What does the set $\{\langle x,y\rangle:y-x=a\}$ look like when you graph it in the plane?

Comment: So basically I would describe the slope from point (x, t) to (y, s)?

Comment: @dxiv: Thanks for catching that; I read too quickly. (Don’t feel the slightest obligation to answer, but just out of curiosity, is that $514$?)

Comment: @ShadowViper: Note that $x+t=y+s$ if and only if $y-x=t-s$, so you really are looking at a set of points for which $y-x$ is a constant. What does that look like when you graph it?

Comment: Funny you'd ask, but it is indeed.